# Where can I get the description of `--shared` option of `git init` command for Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, git, permissions, git-init

I am reading the [Git documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) about the `git init` command:

> **--shared[=(false|true|umask|group|all|world|everybody|0xxx)]** 
> Specify that the Git repository is to be shared amongst several users. This
>   allows users belonging to the same group to push into that repository.
>   When specified, the config variable "core.sharedRepository" is set so
>   that files and directories under $GIT_DIR are created with the
>   requested permissions. When not specified, Git will use permissions
>   reported by umask(2).
>
> The option can have the following values, defaulting to group if no
>   value is given:
>
> **umask (or false)** 
> Use permissions reported by umask(2). The default,
>   when --shared is not specified.
>
> **group (or true)** 
> Make the repository group-writable, (and g+sx, since
>   the git group may be not the primary group of all users). This is used
>   to loosen the permissions of an otherwise safe umask(2) value. Note
>   that the umask still applies to the other permission bits (e.g. if
>   umask is 0022, using group will not remove read privileges from other
>   (non-group) users). See 0xxx for how to exactly specify the repository
>   permissions.
>
> **all (or world or everybody)** 
> Same as group, but make the repository
>   readable by all users.
>
> **0xxx 0xxx** 
> is an octal number and each file will have mode 0xxx. 0xxx
>   will override users' umask(2) value (and not only loosen permissions
>   as group and all does). 0640 will create a repository which is
>   group-readable, but not group-writable or accessible to others. 0660
>   will create a repo that is readable and writable to the current user
>   and group, but inaccessible to others.

This information is for Linux-based OS only. Am I right? But what about Windows? I use [Git for Windows](http://git-for-windows.github.io/). Windows uses ACL instead of umask for working with permissions. :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the Windows permission are translated transparently to the Unix permissions use by Git. So there's no need for a special Windows version of `--shared`. Have you tried running the `umask` in a Bash shell on your Windows?

Comment: Of course, I have tried. You can read my attempt's code here: http://www.git-for-win.red-bee.ru/index.html?file_permissions.html (sorry, that page is Russian, but I have a hope you will be able to understand my code and the output result: `umask` and `--shared` do nothing in the Git Bash for Windows http://git-for-windows.github.io/ ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very sad, but `umask` and `--shared` do nothing in the [Git Bash for Windows](http://git-for-windows.github.io/):

```
Developer@BUSHCOMP MINGW64 /d/temp/000
$ ls -l readme.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 Developer Domain users 0 Sep 10 16:44 readme.txt

Developer@BUSHCOMP MINGW64 /d/temp/000
$ chmod a+rw readme.txt

Developer@BUSHCOMP MINGW64 /d/temp/000
$ ls -l readme.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 Developer Domain users 0 Sep 10 16:44 readme.txt
```

Permissions of the readme.txt wasn't changed: I see `-rw-r--r--` instead of `-rw-rw-rw-`.

```
Developer@BUSHCOMP MINGW64 /d/temp/000
$ chmod 666 readme.txt

Developer@BUSHCOMP MINGW64 /d/temp/000
$ ls -l readme.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 Developer Domain users 0 Sep 10 16:44 readme.txt
```

Permissions of the readme.txt wasn't changed again: I see `-rw-r--r--` instead of `-rw-rw-rw-`.

Ok, I try to use `--shared=0666`:

```
Developer@BUSHCOMP MINGW64 /d/temp/000/111
$ git init --shared=0666
Bare repository is initialized Git в D:/temp/000/111/.git/

Developer@BUSHCOMP MINGW64 /d/temp/000/111 (master)
$ echo 2>test.txt


Developer@BUSHCOMP MINGW64 /d/temp/000/111 (master)
$ git add test.txt

Developer@BUSHCOMP MINGW64 /d/temp/000/111 (master)
$ git commit -m "Test"
[master (root commit) 0d01d64] Test
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 test.txt

Developer@BUSHCOMP MINGW64 /d/temp/000/111 (master)
$ ls -l test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 Developer Domain users 0 Sep 10 17:10 test.txt

At this case I see `-rw-r--r--` instead of `-rw-rw-rw-` also.
```

I've updated Git for Windows from 2.4.5 to 2.5.2 but these problems exist stil.

**UPD**

I got the answer [here](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/379).